# not able to authenticate login user in laravel 9

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-9

I'm using laravel 9 auth to authenticate the user

my Controller code

login function

```
public function authLogin(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|min:5|max:12',
    ]);
    $fnf = User::where('email','=',$request->email)->first();
    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
    if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
        $request->session()->put('LoggedUser', $fnf->uniqueId);
        return redirect('dashboard');
    }else{
        return redirect("/")->with('fail','Please check mail id & password !');
    }
}
```

registration function

```
public function customRegistration(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'firstName' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email|unique:mania_adminauth',
        'number' => 'required|min:10|max:10',
        'password' => 'required|min:6',
    ]);

    $data = $request->all();
    $arrData['firstName'] = $data['firstName'];
    $arrData['lastName'] = $data['lastName'];
    $arrData['email'] =  $data['email'];
    $arrData['number'] =  $data['number'];
    $arrData['password'] = Hash::make($data['password']);
    $arrData['createdOn'] = Carbon::now()->timestamp;
    $table = 'mania_adminauth';
    $user = new commonModal();
    $Response = $user->insertData($table, $arrData);
    if ($Response != 0) {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');
        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
            return redirect("dashboard");
        } else {
            return view('admin.common.registration')->with('fail','Something Went Wrong !!');
        }
    }
}
```

i'm trying to check user is login or not

```
@if (auth()->check())
     <p>User is login.</p>
@else
     <p>User is not login.</p>
@endif
```

but it is showing: "User is not login"

even if i´m logged in

insertData method

```
public function insertData($table_name, $data)
  {
      $resp = DB::table($table_name)->insert($data);
      return $resp;
  }
```

Comment: Are you checked password and login is right?

Comment: I checked password and email on login

Comment: You are using commonModal model as a User auth provider modal

Comment: There is a function name insertData in commonModal which insert data in db
After that I use mail or password to login user then redirect to view

But,when I use auth check in view it's shows only else code

Comment: Can you add to question this insertData method also

Comment: insertData method also ok

Answer (score 0):

Please add this line after Auth::attempt(). I think it's the missing points.

```
$request->session()->regenerate();
```

It looks like this

```
if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) {
    $request->session()->regenerate();
    return redirect("dashboard");
}
```

And it will be run correctly like this